# Custom scope in SharePoint

Tags: search, search-scope, scopedisplaygroup

I need to create a custom scope such that it should point to particular column in a list. Consider i am having a list with column which has values as yes and no. Now i need to create scope for these to values and display that in a scope dropdown for searching. When i selected this scope my search result should be filtered based on this condition also..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1) From Search administration, Do a crawl first (if you recently added the column).

2) Then add a Managed Metadata Property which maps to the particular column. Select "Allow this property to be used in scopes" for the managed property

3) Do a crawl again

4) While Creating a new scope,select "Property Query" as scope rule type.Under Property Query drop-down, you will see the managed property you created. Select it and insert the value you want for comparison in the text box below.

5) After your scope is complied, it is ready to use

Comment: can i display any number of display groups in search page. in this case i need to use separate display group for each scope. i have searched for that but i could find only scope dropdown that too used only once..